# Find similarity percentage of two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table with 4 columns in my database that have many entities. I want to compare all rows with a given sample and calculate the similarity percentage between the rows and the sample.

Suppose that we have 3 rows in this table like this:

```
Franck | 15 | male   | Spain
Hadi   | 20 | male   | Iran
Deniz  | 10 | Female | Turkey
```

and want to search this sample:

```
Hadi | 15 | male | Iran
```

So I want to have results that show the matching percentage between this sample and the rows like this:

```
Franck | 15 | male   | Spain  | 50%
Hadi   | 20 | male   | Iran   | 75%
Deniz  | 10 | Female | Turkey | 0%
```

Are there any tools or common methods that can help me to do this? in SQL Server or Entity framework?

Comment: According to your sentence `calculate the similarity percentage between the rows`, what is exactly the similarity that you mentioned? I mean, how 50%, 75% and 0% calculated. Would you send more examples, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` clause to check for columns and assign values according to your rules. For example:

```
select
  *,
  case when name = 'Hadi' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when age = 15 then 1 else 0 end +
  case when sex = 'male' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when country = 'Iran' then 1 else 0 end 
  * 25 as percent
from t
```

Comment: Thanks for your great solution.